# difference between api call and on postman

Tags: javascript, rest, azure, postman, speech-to-text

I was using Azure Speech rest api. And i tried it on post man with a .wav file and it successfully return the result. However, when i call api from my node.js code. It always return Unsupported Audio Format even though i give the same audio file. Can anyone tell me what's the difference of them? Or what did Postman do to make it work?

Below is how i call speech api by node.js.

```js
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

const subscriptionKey = 'MYSUBSCRIPTIONKEY';

const uriBase = 'https://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US';

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    body: 'speech.wav',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey,
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        'Expect': '100-continue',
        'Content-type':'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000'
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return;
  }
  let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');
  console.log('JSON Response\n');
  console.log(jsonResponse);
});
```

Comment: You need to remove first content-type from headers.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev That's really a mistake. I removed it but it still returns {
  "Message": "Unsupported audio format"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
fs.readFile('/path/to/my/audiofile.wav', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var options = {
    host: 'https://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'audio/wav' }
  };
  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    // Handle a successful response here...
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    // Handle an error response here...
  });
  // Write the audio data in the request body.
  req.write(data);
  req.end();
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. This works on my visual studio code. But I'm wanting it on a browser. Isn't the browser can't support fs module?

Comment: I am not getting you exactly, do you want to show the response from azure api on browser? Can you please be more specific

Comment: YES. I want it on browser. So i should require fs module in the code. Then i use browserify to create a bundle.js in order to make it support "require". But browserify doesn't convert fs module, right?

Comment: What you can do is, expose an api in node, make some action from browser (click or something) call this api, in return put the above code in the function of the exposed api and once you get the response from azure you can jsonify it and send it back to the browser.
Also just a humble request, please accept the answers here on stackoverflow if that solves your issue, it motivates fellow developers to be proactive in answering  questions. Thanks. Do let me know for further details on this. Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks!! And sorry for not accepting. I'm new here. Still trying to know how it works. You definitely help me a lot! Thanks!!